# Is there a way to change the Android status bar color with React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

I just got started with React Native for Android, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to change the status bar color for Android...

Like this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made an npm package to control the StatusBar in android

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-statusbar

The color changes do not reflect for versions before 21

Comment: Thanks for the module! I'm going to mark this as the answer as it seems to be the "React" way to go about it.

Comment: What about coloring the navigation bar?

Comment: I don't think android has released an api for that yet

Comment: But what about coloring 'Action Bar' or 'App Bar' or 'Navigation Bar'?

Answer (score 54):

You can use React Native Status Bar(detailed description [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html)). All you need to do is wrapping navigator with a view and adding a StatusBar component above it. Don't forget to import StatusBar from 'react-native' package.

```
<View>
  <StatusBar
    backgroundColor="blue"
    barStyle="light-content"
  />
  <Navigator
    initialRoute={{statusBarHidden: true}}
    renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
      <View>
        <StatusBar hidden={route.statusBarHidden} />
         ...
      </View>
    }
  />
</View>
```

One thing I've noticed is that you should style the parent View with *flex:1*, without it you'll just see a white blank screen. It's not mentioned in RN Documents though.

Comment: This works and editing styles.xml in android project won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Navigator is deprecated now. So looking for a better solution.

Comment: StatusBar is a component, use it with any navigator you like. It was just an example

Comment: Helpful tip on styling the top view with flex:1

Answer (score 25):

You can use `react-native` in-build `StatusBar` function

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';

render() {
  return <View>
     <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="#264d9b"
        barStyle="light-content"
     />
     ... //Your code
   </View>
}
```

reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar

Answer (score 24):

Yes you can:

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
  StatusBar.setBarStyle( 'light-content',true)
  StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("#0996AE")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way currently to do that from JS. You can customize it by using a custom theme. Check out `android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` file from your project (template is here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) and read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot that there's an actual Java project underneath the React Native stuff. Though I guess I'll have to use a values-21 folder as the colorPrimary/colorPrimaryDark stuff is only available on Lollipop and above. Or bring in AppCompat...

Answer (score 6):

Add this code on your header component

```
androidStatusBarColor="#34495e"
```

Answer (score 6):

add **color.xml** in *..android/app/src/main/res/values* and pate following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--   color for the app bar and other primary UI elements -->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>

    <!--   a darker variant of the primary color, used for
           the status bar (on Android 5.0+) and contextual app bars -->
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#A52D53</color>

    <!--   a secondary color for controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

copy and pate following code in  *..android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>    
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Expo for React Native then here is the solution for setting Android Status Bar Color.

First of all, In your app.json file add the code:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "Your given Version",
    "androidStatusBar": {
       "backgroundColor": "#4e2ba1" (Your desirable android Status Bar Color before the app loads)
    }
   }    
}
```

And then Go to Your Main Component or App.js, import 'StatusBar' from 'react-native'. Then add Following Code in return:

```
return(
   <View style={{flex: 1}}>  (Do not forget to style flex as 1)
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"/>
      <Your Code>
   </View>
);
```

Here, we are setting the status bar color as Black but with 0.2 opacity. Your statusBar Color will be the same as your headerStyle background Color for Stack Navigator but a bit darker. For standard Android App, this is how the StatusBar color is set. Also, Make it translucent so that your app draws under the status Bar and looks nice.

It hope this works perfectly for you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exposed API for now. This will work only from Android 5.0.
Working on a bridge module to achieve the same. Will keep you posted

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following code to your App.js file inside your class component.

```
    componentDidMount(){
        StatusBar.setBarStyle( 'light-content',true)
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("Your color Hex-code here")
    }
```

And add this to your import statements.

```
    import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you guys are using expo then just add this in the app.json

```
"androidStatusBar": {
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
  "barStyle":"dark-content"
}
```

Refer: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/

Answer (score 1):

Use **backgroundColor** Prop in the StatusBar Component

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="#yourColor" />
```

Check docs more information : https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-navigation-bar-color](https://github.com/thebylito/react-native-navigation-bar-color) this module to change NavigationBar, install it using `npm i react-native-navigation-bar-color`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expo package NavigationBar to change color of Android navigation bar: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/

There is also a package to change the StatusBar color.