# Change navigation bar color

Tags: react-native, expo

I know it is possible since API 21 to change the color of the navigation bar. I have looked at the documentation of React Native but I can not find a way to do this.

The only way I know is by creating a native module, but that does not seem like a good solution since I am using Expo.

Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: You mean Status bar color? That appears on top of screen?

Comment: @BhavanPatel No, the navigation bar on the bottom of the screen. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I had made one plugin for that it is use full to achieve what you want.

https://github.com/BhavanPatel/react-native-navbar-color

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navbar-color

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for!

Answer (score 33):

(For those using react-native-cli) Just add `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#0D0D0D</item>`  to your style in `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#0D0D0D</item> <!--  ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR styles.xml    -->
</style>
```

Comment: what about dynamic?

Answer (score 7):

I created a package with color replacement and more.

react-native-system-navigation-bar

**Install**

```
yarn add react-native-system-navigation-bar
```

or

```
npm install react-native-system-navigation-bar
```

**Links**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-navigation-bar

https://github.com/kadiraydinli/react-native-system-navigation-bar

Comment: That was a great job you did here. You did solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

### For `react-navigation` v6:

Simply set `navigationbarColor` in the navigator:

```js
screenOptions={{navigationBarColor: 'gold'}}
```

Comment: It is only available when using `@react-navigation/native-stack` and not present in `@react-navigation/stack`

Answer (score 3):

Below is another choice. It has recent commits.

react-native-navigation-bar-color

https://github.com/thebylito/react-native-navigation-bar-color

Comment: Very un-useful module

Answer (score 2):

With the latest versions of Expo you can install the module

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/ then in your App.js

you make import of `import * as NavigationBar from 'expo-navigation-bar';`

and you can then set `NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("color of your choice");` in your body

Answer (score 0):

The other possible ways to change background color of Status Bar and Navigation Bar of Android Device is through `StatusBar` module and `NativeModules`

I already post my answer about NaigationBar of Android, you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66415888/10646511)