# I can't customize the navigation bar in my React Native android app

Tags: react-native

I'm writing an android application using React Native, but I can't customize the color of the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. How can I customize it? Please help me as soon as possible. Thank you

I've tried everything and it only seems to work in IOS. Is there any way to work with android
[image]

Comment: Show your code and what library you use, please

Comment: I'm sorry, i used react-native-safe-area-context library in React Native project. Help me, pls

Comment: As far as I understand, it duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928061/change-navigation-bar-color

Comment: I'm sorry, but I want to edit it in React Native code, not directly on the platform. Because there are levels I don't want to customize again. Is there any other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Expo:**

```
npx expo install expo-navigation-bar
```

```js
import * as NavigationBar from 'expo-navigation-bar'

NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("color of your choice")
```

- **React Native Cli:**

There are many library support you to change navigation bar color:

1. [react-native-system-navigation-bar](https://github.com/kadiraydinli/react-native-system-navigation-bar)

```js
import SystemNavigationBar from 'react-native-system-navigation-bar';

SystemNavigationBar.setNavigationColor('red');
```

2. [react-native-navigation-bar-color](https://github.com/thebylito/react-native-navigation-bar-color)

```js
example = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await changeNavigationBarColor('#80b3ff', true);
    console.log(response)// {success: true}
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e)// {success: false}
  }
};
```