# Change Color ActionBar React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

How can i change the color of the Action Bar in all the page of my Android App in React Native?
The area where is the text "Testo"

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the Android status bar color with React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750260/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-android-status-bar-color-with-react-native)

Comment: That doesn't seem like a native navigation bar. Can you add some code to show how these views are setup?