# Change navigation bar on android with RN with expo?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I started using React Native with Expo and I encountered my first problem. I want to change the color of the navigation bar on Android. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do that.

[image]

I tried to use https://github.com/thebylito/react-native-navigation-bar-color#readme but it prints out the following error:

> TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NavigationBarColor.changeNavigationBarColor')

```js
if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
  changeNavigationBarColor('#f00', true);
}
```

Comment: Did you install 'react-native-navigation-bar-color'?

Comment: Did you import `changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color'`?

Comment: yes, `react-native-navigation-bar-color` is installed, linked and imported

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This functionality was merged into expo on Aug 9th.
You need to add these directives to app.json

```
{
  "androidNavigationBar": {
     /*
        Determines to show or hide bottom navigation bar.
        "true" to show, "false" to hide.
        If set to false, status bar will also be hide. As it's a general rule to hide both status bar and navigation bar on Android developer official docs.
      */
    "visible": BOOLEAN,
    /*
      Configure the navigation bar icons to have light or dark color.
      Valid values: "light-content", "dark-content".
    */
    "barStyle": STRING,

    /*
      Configuration for android navigation bar.
      6 character long hex color string, eg: "#000000"
    */
    "backgroundColor": STRING
  }
}
```

Here's the pull request with more information https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/5280

Comment: Yes, that help, but still we cant make it transparent or change options when application is running.

Comment: To get more control at this time, you would need to eject (https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/workflow/customizing/) to be able to link a native module like react-native-navigation-bar-color. You will not be able to use any module that needs to be linked inside expo. You can also request that feature here https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests

Answer (score 2):

So now you can change the color of `NavigationBar` on the fly.

Expo released a package - [expo-navigation-bar](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/)

Simply install it

```js
expo install expo-navigation-bar
```

Usage is well explained in the docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/#api)

For changing the navigation bar color simply run,

```js
NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("white");
```

Comment: [TypeError: _ExpoNavigationBar.default.setBackgroundColorAsync is not a function. (In '_ExpoNavigationBar.default.setBackgroundColorAsync(colorNumber)', '_ExpoNavigationBar.default.setBackgroundColorAsync' is undefined)]

Comment: Have you imported it correctly? `import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar`

Comment: I have the same error as IMPixel, I use the same import as you mention, present inside Expo docs.
But when I trying to console log the function, it's showing that it's indeed a function, but return the promise error

Answer (score 0):

Did you install 'react-native-navigation-bar-color'?

If not

1. `npm install react-native-navigation-bar-color --save`
2. `react-native link react-native-navigation-bar-color`

And

Did you import changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color'?

If not `import changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';`

OR

The name of the color is not clear. an example of color

```
white : "#ffffff" , black : "#000000"
```

use reac-native-navigation-bar-color:

```js
example = async () => {
      try{
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
          const response = await changeNavigationBarColor('#ffffff');
          console.log(response)// {success: true}
          }
      }catch(e){
          console.log(e)// {success: false}
      }

  };
...
<Button
          title="Set color white"
          onPress={() => {
            this.example();
          }}
        />
```

IF not I suggest you try another module. `react-native-navbar-color`

1. `npm install --save react-native-navbar-color`
2. `react-native link react-native-navbar-color`

Example.js

```js
import NavigationBar from 'react-native-navbar-color'

export default class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        NavigationBar.setColor('#ffab8e')
    }
...
```

[Description of the module](https://github.com/BhavanPatel/react-native-navbar-color)

Comment: yes, `react-native-navigation-bar-color` is installed, linked and imported. I tried to changed color to '#ffffff' and still same error

Comment: @WojciechBorowski  updated my answer. You can try my answer code

Comment: same problem with async `null is not an object (evaluating 'NavigationBarColor.changeNavigationBarColor')
- node_modules/react-native-navigation-bar-color/src/index.js:8:23 in changeNavigationBarColor`

Comment: Can you try this? import { changeNavigationBarColor } from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';

Comment: i get different error `(0, _reactNativeNavigationBarColor.changeNavigationBarColor) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNativeNavigationBarColor.changeNavigationBarColor)('#ffffff')', '(0, _reactNativeNavigationBarColor.changeNavigationBarColor)' is undefined)`

Comment: @WojciechBorowski I found another module to help you. Please refer to the answer.

Comment: same problem TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NavigationBar.setColor')

Comment: I think something is not installed properly. Check the module homepage to see if there are any missing.

Comment: maybe it's because I use Expo Managed Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

This module does not work with Expo. Make sure you checkout the **READ ME** file for any module you want to install with Expo.

If you see the installation step requires '**react-native link module-name**' then most likely **it won't work** with Expo unless it's already included/pre-packaged in the Expo SDK version you have.

I've learned my lesson the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

The other possible way to change background color of Status Bar and Navigation Bar of Android Device is through `StatusBar` module and `NativeModules`

and you may apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66415888/10646511) answer to your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but I found that I was importing the method like this:

```
import { changeNavigationBarColor } from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';
```

So I switched to this:

```
import changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';
```

And then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I tried many answers throughout the forums but couldn't find the working solution. Finally below worked for me and will for you if you are using latest RN [0.62 https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation)

You can also set header background instead of backgroundColor. Below is my code:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Main}
            options={{ title: 'Welcome', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#e7305b'
           } }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: OP is asking about the bottom navigation bar on Android, on RN using Expo.

Comment: I don't know maybe original question edited later or screen shot added. Also on stack overflow their is no spoon feeding, I told user how to change navigation bar, he can use similar approach for his problem. Thanks.